# Insert a Column of json Object to New Column via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I Have a json Column and I Want to Collect `id` to a New Column With `id2` Name.
   **This Is one Row of json Column**

```
[{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"a"},
 {"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"b"},
 {"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"c"}]
```

I Mean How to add `26,30,31 40,40,10 52,12,12` to New Column.
My Table Name is `user_survey_start` My json Column Name is `survey_answers`and My New id Column is `id2`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT `survey_answers` FROM `user_survey_start`";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $json = $row[0];
        $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);

        // id   
        $id = array();
        foreach ($jason_array as $data){
            $id[] = $data['id'];
            // here code to insert/update values to db column
        }
        echo implode(',',$id)."</br>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. You want to update your JSON object to include a new property called `id2` ?

Comment: I Want to add `26,30,31
40,40,10
52,12,12` to New Column

Comment: can you update your question to include your final desired output please so it's clear.

Comment: Updated.. I Want to Split `id` and Put to New Column

Comment: You keep saying that, but I don't know what you mean.

Comment: My json Is `id` and `awnser` and `type`,  How Can i Insert `id` To a New Column With `id2` Name.

Comment: Just modify your json array, and then do a `$newJson = json_encode($jsonArray);`

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he is getting the JSON string from one column in the DB, and wants to insert the collected IDs into a different column of the same record (or maybe in a different table?). If that's the case, you would use either an UPDATE sql statement (former) or an INSERT sql statement (later case).

Comment: Yes i want Collect id into id2 in this table, i will update my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved With This Code

```
         $id = array(); 
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                            $id[] = $data['id'];
                        }
                        $ids= implode(',',$id);
                        $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where id_s=".$row[1];//run update sql
                        echo $sql1."<br>";
                        mysqli_query($con,$sql1);               
        // awnser2          
        $answers = array();
        foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                $answers[] =$ans['text'] ;
                }
        }
        $answers= implode(',',$answers);
        $sql3="update user_survey_start set awnser2='$answers' where id_s=".$row[1];//run update sql
        echo $sql3."<br>";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql3);                                                                           
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to update your table schema, so it will have new column named `id2`.

```
ALTER TABLE `user_survey_start` ADD `id2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

You can delete `NOT` from `NOT NULL` if you want this column to be optional.

Then you just only have to insert these IDs from JSON to your newly created `id2` column.

```
$id = implode(',', $id);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `user_survey_start` SET `id2` = $id WHERE `id` = {$row['id']}");
```

Comment: I Updated My Table Currectly and added your code after foreach, But I have Error Can You Correct My Code Please.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php on line 25

Comment: Replace `id` index at the end of `mysqli_query` to the name of your id column.

Comment: Go into phpMyAdmin, navigate to your `user_survey_start` table, go to *structure* and look at the very first column which should be `PRIMARY KEY`. Replace `id` index at the end of query with the name of this column.

Comment: I Changed id with my column name ` mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `user_survey_start` SET `id2` = $id WHERE `survey_answers` = {$row['id']}");
` But I Have error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136022/discussion-between-albert221-and-sedric-heidarizarei).

Comment: I Still Have Error, Can You Check That? Make a Test Db For Yourself And Solve My Problem Please.

Comment: I Solved This, `$id = array(); 
    foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
        $id[] = $data['id'];
       }
       $ids= implode(',',$id);
       $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where id_s=".$row[1];//run update sql
       echo $sql1."<br>";
       mysqli_query($con,$sql1);`